# Conditionally add plugin usage in NextJS app to prevent warning errors

Tags: next.js, postcss

I am getting errors when I run: "npm run dev" because I am exporting nothing out because it conditionally sets the plugins depending on environment. Is there a cleaner way to fix this?

error:
You did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.

reason:
In "dev" I export out an empty plugins.

```
module.exports = !isProduction ? {
  plugins: []
} : {
  plugins: [
       "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
       [
        "postcss-preset-env",
          {
            autoprefixer: { flexbox: "no-2009" },
            stage: 3,
            features: { "custom-properties": false }
          }
       ],
      [
        "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
          {
            content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
            defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            safelist: ["html", "body"]
          }
      ]
     ]

};
```

Comment: which version of Next.js you use?

Comment: I am using version 11